# DRF APITestCase but ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html; charset=utf-8", not "application/json"

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm trying to make unittest by django and DRF

but I have a problem when running test

the below code is my tests, views, models code

I check urls and runserver too and they work well.

I need your help.

tests.py

```
class TestCohorts(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        models.Cohort.objects.create(code=COHORT_CODE)

    def test_cohort(self):
        response = self.client.get("api/v1/cohort")
        print(response)
        data = response.json()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, "status code is not 200.")
```

views.py

```
class CohortList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.Cohort.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CohortSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Cohort(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.code}"

    class Meta:
        db_table = "cohort"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("api/v1/cohort", views.CohortList.as_view()),]
```

the traceback is

````
  File "/BiO/Preprocessing/Rplite/raptor_platform/information/tests.py", line 24, in test_cohort
    data = response.json()
  File "/BiO/home/jhpark/.local/share/virtualenvs/Rplite-i3g_nsgq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 823, in _parse_json
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html; charset=utf-8", not "application/json" ```
````

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: The line is `test_cohort data = response.json()`, but that is not in the shared test?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What it that mean shared test? the test run catched my test but get url is not working

Comment: the error is about a line `test_cohort data = response.json()`, but in the test in your question, there is no such line.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my first code tests.py 

    `def test_cohort(self):
        response = self.client.get("api/v1/cohort")
        print(response)
        data = response.json() <- here is the line`

Comment: @jilheyon: but that says `data = `...